# python - list of dict; names of which from list of strings

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm kinda new to python, & the thing i'm trying to do is as follows (Python 2.7)

- I have a list of strings that looks like:

  my_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', ]
- My aim is to create a list of dictionaries which will look like (same names):

  dict_list = [a1, a2, a3, ]
- where each item  will represent a dictionary (all dictionaries will have same keys)

  a1 = {name:a1, value:70, id:1,}
  a2 = {name:a2, value:80, id:1,}

  etc...

if you can explain as dummy proof as possible =)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[{'name': my_list[i], 'id': i} for i in xrange(len(my_list))]` should roughly do the trick (you haven't explained where the values are supposed to come from so it's not perfect). Look up list comprehensions.